# Elm code for splitting a string into list of tuples containing character and its index position

Tags: string, list, tuples, elm

I have a string `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`. I would like to build a list of tuples containing the character and its index position.

For example if

```
string = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz"
```

I would like to build a list containing

```
slist  = [(0,'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')...]
```

How to do this in `Elm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings in Elm are not lists, so first you have to convert it using `String.toList`. You can then zip it up with an index using the built-in `List.indexedMap` function.

```elm
import List exposing (indexedMap)
import String exposing (toList)

getIndexedCharacters : String -> List (Int, Char)
getIndexedCharacters =
  indexedMap (,) << toList
```